# How to use javascript to append values to my own google sheet using Google Sheet Api (Without OAuth 2.0)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

I am writing a bookmarklet to execute it in webpage to grab some data and save it to my private google sheet, append to the last row using this method: spreadsheets.values.append

I have enabled Google Sheets API. And generated an API Key and the application restriction is none, and the API restrictions is "Don't restrict key".

Once I execute my code, I got 401 response.

When I tried to use "Try this method" from Google Sheet Reference, it shows:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.AppendValues",
          "service": "sheets.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it anyway to use API key to append rows to my own Google Sheet?

Following is my javascript code:

```js
var sheetId = "MY_SHEET_ID";
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";

var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + sheetId + "/values/" + sheetName + "!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";
var data = [["test value"]];

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};

var jsonData = {
  "range": sheetName,
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": data
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, if your `apiKey` of `"Bearer " + apiKey` is not the access token, please use the access token and test it again.

Comment: I agree with [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike). With this particular method you would need to use an access token instead of an API key since it is not supported by the method. You can make the same test using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append). Once you test using the access token let us know if that worked for you.